# HTML5 and <table> "style" attribute

Tags: html, attributes, formatting

I´ve just started learining this new, wonderful skill (HTML5) and everything was going smooth up untill I got to able styling. OK, I know that CSS is made for that, but as it´s a little bit too early for me I use ´style´ attribute. OK, so I wrote this simple table:

```
<!Doctype html>

<html lang="es-es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>First table</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Kamila Bertran">
    </head>

    <body>

        <table style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”>

            <caption> Gastos mensuales </caption>

            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Producto </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Unidades </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Precio </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Total </td>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2 style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%; align:center;”> Año 2014</td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Total</td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 142 </td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot> 

            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Camisetas </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 10 </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 2 </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 20 </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Pantalones </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 3 </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 14 </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 42 </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> Chaquetas </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 4 </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 20 </td>
                <td style=”border:1px solid #000; width:100%;”> 80 </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

and cannot undestand why my ´style´ attribute is being completly ignored. Help?

Comment: As an immediate reaction - I've not studied it closely - but: it's 'width' not 'witdh'.

Comment: ...And I forgot to mention - I was wondering about your quotation marks - you should use either (")- double quotes, or (') single quote - chr(34) or chr(39), Yours look different, but that may just be how it appears here.

Comment: I really got to say this....my immediate reaction was to search google if this was some kind of new language to specify width. :D

Comment: yes, the devil is always in detail. Quotation marks corrected. Thx. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you used ( ” ).This is wrong.You must use ( " )
Like this

```
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid #000; width:100%;">Camisetas</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid #000; width:100%;">10</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid #000; width:100%;">2</td>
            <td style="border:1px solid #000; width:100%;">20</td>
        </tr>
```

Also

Comment: Thx, I did not spot that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Its not a Good Practice to use inline styling. I have optimised the code with the use of CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="tblBorder">
  <caption> Gastos mensuales </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Producto </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Unidades </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Precio </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Total </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan=2 class="tblBorder center"> Año 2014</td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Total</td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 142 </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Camisetas </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 10 </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 2 </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 20 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Pantalones </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 3 </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 14 </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 42 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tblBorder"> Chaquetas </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 4 </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 20 </td>
      <td class="tblBorder"> 80 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.tblBorder
{
  border:1px solid #000; width:100%;
}
.center
{
 align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First table</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Kamila Bertran">
    <style>
    table{
        border:1px solid #000; width:100%;
    }
    td{
        border:1px solid #000; width:100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table>

        <caption> Gastos mensuales </caption>

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> Producto </td>
            <td> Unidades </td>
            <td> Precio </td>
            <td> Total </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2 align="center"> Año 2014</td>
            <td> Total</td>
            <td> 142 </td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot> 

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> Camisetas </td>
            <td> 10 </td>
            <td> 2 </td>
            <td> 20 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Pantalones </td>
            <td> 3 </td>
            <td> 14 </td>
            <td> 42 </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td> Chaquetas </td>
            <td> 4 </td>
            <td> 20 </td>
            <td> 80 </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

</body>
```

In HTML align is attribute. So you can do **align="center"** and instead of writing **inline css** you can right **Internal or External css** with using class or HTML element name.So that line of code will get reduce.